# How to use affineTransform on subset of CAEAGLLayer (iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, core-graphics, core-animation

I am playing around with Open GL and core animation and have been able to do affine transforms on open GL layers and everything works great.  Looking for help on how would I transform a subset of a layer, meaning a top half or bottom quarter and only rotate those pixels while keeping the rest of the layer untouched.

Alternatively if I have 1 openGL layer would it be possible to split it into 2 (top and bottom sections).  Then I can perform transforms as needed.  I cannot access the subviews in the layer, only the layer as a whole.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in the view pipeline you would need multiple views. In general there is nothing wrong with that but you will need to do a bit of work to draw to each of the views so that it seems as a whole. If you are using standard projection matrices such as `glOrtho` you only need to split the border parameters (top, bottom, left and right) accordingly to your view split.

To do it with openGL directly there are multiple ways. Which to choose depends on your needs.

One way is to use viewport. This describes what part of the buffer you are drawing to so you can split it into multiple draw calls drawing to different positions. This is generally more useful for view within the view situation.

Probably the best way would be to draw the whole scene to a FBO (frame buffer object) with attached texture. Then create sprites (rectangles) which you want to animate and then draw parts of the texture to those rectangles.

Still then you need a system which is able to animate within the openGL. To achieve that you need to do a matrix interpolation. It might take a bit of time but is generally worth it as you have a total control over the animations and how they are done. Note that due to rotations you will need to do the interpolation in the polar coordinate system which means transforming the 3 base vectors (top left 3x3 part of the matrix) to angle+radius and interpolate those.